# How to add hyperlink to custom case numbers in Reports

Tags: custom-field, custom-report-type

We have a visualforce page which is used to input details about quality issues and create cases. I've created a custom case number field for newly created cases in an auto-numbered format. I've to create reports of these new cases based on it's status. Once I run the report, I want the custom case number to be rendered with a hyperlink, by which, I can directly browse to the case by clicking on the custom case number, just as the way for a standard case number. I would like to ignore the standard case numbers in reporting to avoid confusion among the users. How do I create the hyperlink? I want the below case numbers starting with QR to be in hyperlink. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new formula field, `Case_Number_Link__c`, to your Cases, using a formula like this example:

```
HYPERLINK("/" & Id, My_Custom_Case_Number__c)
```

Then, show the formula field on your report canvas in place of the real custom case number field. You'll be able to click through directly to the Case.

Comment: remember to accept the answer =)